# C - Segfault when accessing struct member in a HashTable (insert function)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and am having issues implementing an insert function for my HashTable.

Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct HashTableNode {
    char *url;                               // url previously seen
    struct HashTableNode *next;              // pointer to next node
} HashTableNode;

typedef struct HashTable {
    HashTableNode *table[MAX_HASH_SLOT];     // actual hashtable
} HashTable;
```

Here is how I init the table:

```
HashTable *initTable(){
  HashTable* d = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_HASH_SLOT; i++) {
    d->table[i] = NULL;
  }
  return d;
}
```

Here is my insert function:

```
int HashTableInsert(HashTable *table, char *url){

    long int hashindex = JenkinsHash(url, MAX_HASH_SLOT);
    int uniqueBool = 2; // 0 for true, 1 for false, 2 for init

    HashTableNode* theNode = (HashTableNode*)malloc(sizeof(HashTableNode));
    theNode->url = url;

    if (table->table[hashindex] != NULL) { // if we have a collision

        HashTableNode* currentNode = (HashTableNode*)malloc(sizeof(HashTableNode)); 
        currentNode = table->table[hashindex]->next; // the next node in the list


        if (currentNode == NULL) { // only one node currently in list


           if (strcmp(table->table[hashindex]->url, theNode->url) != 0) { // unique node

                table->table[hashindex]->next = theNode; 
                return 0; 
           }
           else{
            printf("Repeated Node\n");
            return 1;
           }


        }
        else { // multiple nodes in this slot

            printf("There was more than one element in this slot to start with. \n");
            while (currentNode != NULL)
            {


            // SEGFAULT when accessing currentNode->url HERE
               if (strcmp(currentNode->url, table->table[hashindex]->url) == 0 ){ // same URL 

                    uniqueBool = 1; 
               }
               else{
                    uniqueBool = 0; 
               }

                currentNode = currentNode->next;

            }   
        }

        if (uniqueBool == 0) {

            printf("Unique URL\n");

            theNode->next = table->table[hashindex]->next; // splice current node in

            table->table[hashindex]->next = theNode; // needs to be a node for each slot
            return 0; 
            }

    }
    else{

        printf("simple placement into an empty slot\n");
        table->table[hashindex] = theNode; 

    }   

    return 0; 

}
```

I get SegFault every time I try to access currentNode->url (the next node in the linked list of a given slot), which SHOULD have a string in it if the node itself is not NULL.

I know this code is a little dicey, so thank you in advance to anyone up for the challenge.

Chip

UPDATE:

this is the function that calls all ht functions. Through my testing on regular strings in main() of hash table.c, I have concluded that the segfault is due to something here:

```
void crawlPage(WebPage * page){

   char * new_url = NULL;  

   int pos= 0;

   pos = GetNextURL(page->html, pos, URL_PREFIX, &new_url);

   while (pos != -1){


        if (HashTableLookup(URLsVisited, new_url) == 1){ // url not in table

            printf("url is not in table......\n");

            hti(URLsVisited, new_url);

            WebPage * newPage = (WebPage*) calloc(1, sizeof(WebPage));
            newPage->url = new_url;


            printf("Adding to LIST...\n");
            add(&URLList, newPage); // added & to it.. no seg fault 


        }
        else{
            printf("skipping url cuz it is already in table\n");
        }


        new_url = NULL; 

        pos = GetNextURL(page->html, pos, URL_PREFIX, &new_url);

    }

    printf("freeing\n");
    free(new_url); // cleanup
    free(page); // free current page
}
```

Comment: How do you know the problem isn't with the other argument in that call to `strcmp`?

Comment: Anytime you see `ptrvar = allocation(...);`, then `ptrvar = something else;` on the *very next line* consider it a giant red flag. you just leaked memory. The first two lines inside your `table->table[hashindex]  != NULL` if-conditional block do just that.

Comment: Scott, I tested the first arg to strcmp by attempting to simply print the string to the console, with no luck. I will test the second one now, but I am positive that the first one is the main issue.

Comment: Where does the `char*` you pass in to this thing come from ? The code appears to assume ownership of that pointer within the allocated HashTableNode, which obviously won't work if it is, in fact, the same repeatedly used buffer address (or an out of scope automatic buffer) on the caller side. Besides the obvious memory problem I pointed out earlier, a `main()` that triggers the problem by initializing a new hash table and triggering the issue with inserted data would be most-helpful.

Comment: I assume that, because I allocated space for a node and set it equal to a node that I know is not NULL (in that memory leak line) , the url char * member also exists because a node shouldn't exist if it doesn't have a url or a next pointer. To me it seems like there is in fact a node there (due to the if check to see if the slot is not NULL , but for some reason the char * is invalid. I will whip up a main(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hash table insertion logic violates some rather fundamental rules.

- Allocating a new node before determining you actually *need* one.
- Blatant memory leak in your `currentNode` allocation
- Suspicious ownership semantics of the `url` pointer.

Beyond that, this algorithm is being made *way* too complicated for what it really should be.

- Compute the hash index via hash-value modulo the table size.
- Start at the table slot of the hash index, walking node pointers until one of two things happens:

  1. You discover the node is already present
  2. You reach the end of the collision chain.

Only in #2 above do you actually allocate a collision node and chain it to your existing collision list. Most of this is *trivial* when employing a pointer-to-pointer approach, which I demonstrate below:

```
int HashTableInsert(HashTable *table, const char *url)
{
    // find collision list starting point
    long int hashindex = JenkinsHash(url, MAX_HASH_SLOT);
    HashTableNode **pp = table->table+hashindex;

    // walk the collision list looking for a match
    while (*pp && strcmp(url, (*pp)->url))
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (!*pp)
    {
        // no matching node found. insert a new one.
        HashTableNode *pNew = malloc(sizeof *pNew);
        pNew->url = strdup(url);
        pNew->next = NULL;
        *pp = pNew;
    }
    else
    {   // url already in the table
        printf("url \"%s\" already present\n", url);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That really is all there is to it.

The `url` ownership issue I mentioned earlier is addressed above via string duplication using `strdup()`. Although not a standard library function, it is POSIX compliant and every non-neanderthal half-baked implementation I've seen in the last two decades provides it. If yours doesn't (a) I'd like to know what you're using, and (b) its trivial to implement with `strlen` and `malloc`. Regardless, when the nodes are being released during value-removal or table wiping, be sure and `free` a node's `url` before `free`-ing the node itself.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I think the issue is how I am passing the char * in my crawlPage() above. Regardless, this info is very helpful.